# How to pass more data on function Meteor.loginWithFacebook()?

Tags: javascript, meteor, cookies

I'm using

`Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password);`

but I want to pass cookie when creating user. I can't acces cookies server-side, so I need to pass them.

Also, I can't receive new Id of that user, because loginWithFacebook doesn't return Id in callback, so I don't know how to proceed.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
console.log(options);
//how I pass something to options here?
}
return user; 
});
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't pass anything to `onCreateUser`. But you can work around it by creating a custom Meteor method for account creation.

```js
Meteor.methods({
  "registerUser": function(email, password, favouritePony) {
    // You can use your custom parameter
    if (favouritePony === "Pinkie Pie") throw new Meteor.Error("Invalid pony");

    let userId = Accounts.createUser({email, password});
    // Do whatever you want with "userId" here
  }
});
```

And on the client side:

```
registerUser(email, password, pony) {
  Meteor.call("registerUser", email, password, pony, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {...}
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think one can pass stuff within the options parameter. This worked for me:

`Accounts.createUser({
              email: email,
              password: pwText,
              _id: 'blablabla'
            },function(error){`

on the server:

`Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
    console.log(options._id); //returns 'blablabla'
}`

Comment: I came here because I'd like to do the same with the Facebook login, but haven't figured it out yet :( any ideas/hints?